# Poison Quill and Spiked Tail

Tags: king-of-tokyo

In King of Tokyo should Poison Quills activate Spiked Tail?

[image: Poison Quills]

> When you roll 2, 2, 2 or more add Fist, fist to your roll.

[image: Spiked Tail]

> When you roll at least one fist, add fist to your roll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The same question was asked on [BBG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2477079/few-rules-questions-card-interactions).

> Poison Quills+ Spiked Tail, you get all the Claws. There isn't really
> a hard ruling on this, but if you need one I'd go with "you can
> resolve die faces in the order of you're choosing". So just resolve
> the 2's first, then you'll have a Claw to trigger Spiked.